# Xamarin.Forms XAML: Items are hidden/shorter if there are added new items

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a XAML file, combined from ScrollView -> StackLayout -> mulstiple StackLayouts.
Some of those are bound to view model property and displayed only on some occassions. The problem is, where there are like 3 (or something like that) new items, they are not all displayed, and some of they existing ones gets shorter.

For example:
My screen now: Label-entry-label-entry-label-entry-label-entry-label-progressbar-label-label-button

My screen after some work: Label-entry-label-entry-label-entry-label-entry-label-progressbar-label-label-label-label-button (two new labels before button).

The second new label is not displayed, and also the button like 20% of its original height. I can fix this if I click on entry (dont need to type anything), and close the keyboard. Then its displayed OK, but I have no idea how. I dont even know how can i debug this, heh. Any idea?
edit: i think the stacklayout doesn't resize to scrollview height. I set scrollview background color to green, and stacklayout to red. Before changes, there is only red background. after I add some new elements, there is a few rows of new green background (just the right height for those missing/shorter items...

My scroolview and stacklayout start code:

```
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Padding="10,20,10,10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding StackVisible}">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="Select item"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Picker IsEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding PickerSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPickerItem}">
                    </Picker>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" IsVisible="{Binding UrlVisible}">
                    <Label Text="URL:" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Url}" FontSize="15"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" IsVisible="{Binding UserPassVisible}">
                    <Label Text="Username" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Username}" FontSize="15"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" IsVisible="{Binding UserPassVisible}">
                    <Label Text="Password" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" FontSize="15" IsPassword="True"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Label Text="{Binding ProgressText}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20" />
                <ProgressBar ProgressColor="{Binding ProgressBarColor}" Opacity="{Binding ProgressBarOpacity}" WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label IsVisible="{Binding ResultVisible}" TextColor="{Binding StatusColor}" Text="{Binding ResultText}}" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label IsVisible="{Binding ErrorBoxVisible}" Text="{Binding ErrorText}" FontSize="18" TextColor="#f44336" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label IsVisible="{Binding DurationVisible}"  Text="{Binding Duration}" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Counter1Visible}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0">
                <StackLayout WidthRequest="100">
                    <Image Source="iconUp" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Counter1}" FontSize="25" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="100"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding Counter2Visible}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
                <StackLayout WidthRequest="100">
                    <Image Source="iconDown" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Counter2}" FontSize="25" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontAttributes="Bold" WidthRequest="100"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Button IsEnabled="{Binding BtnEnabled}" FontSize="15" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="100" Text="ClickMe" Command="{Binding BtnClick}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: instead of *describing* the code, please post the actual code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Done. If I enable those Counter1Visible, Counter2Visible, ErrorBoxVisible,ResultVisible, the Bottom button gets pushed "out" of the top StackLayout, because it doesnt resize as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a StackLayout out of the scrollView.

Please refer the following code:

```
 <!--add a StackLayout out of the ScrollView-->
 <StackLayout>

    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Padding="10,20,10,10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
          <!--other code-->

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

 </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi @yeetyeet, just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.